# import to separate publication lists based on opt preferences

Tags: marketing-cloud, email-studio, publicationlist, preference-center

I am supporting the implementation of SFMC for a client and presented with this scenario. Leads, contacts, and opportunities are synchronized to their SF CRM via marketing Cloud Connect.

As per their requirements, I have built a master data extension utilizing SQL query that joins contacts that have an associated opportunity ( matching on contactId available on both ).

1. there are 3 publication lists to be created.
2. they have been tracking consent via a third party and want to provide up-to-date file of unsubs, hard bounces, and a file providing who is opted out of which communication(publication list).

I need to match the master list mentioned earlier and import &/or unsub/opt-out the correct subscribers from the correct publication lists while importing the ones subscribed to the correct publication lists. This is a one-time process due to migration.

How should I go about doing this so that ultimately I end up with the publication lists containing the master list records based on their consent preferences?